# Transparent Header in NavigationExperimental

Tags: react-native, navigation, transparent

it's been a while since i am trying to make the `header` bar transparent in `react-native` with `NavigationExperimental` but no luck, can any one tell me how to do it ?

[image: transparent header]

here's my code

```
return (<NavHeader
      {...props}
      style={styles.headerStyle}
      renderTitleComponent={this.renderTitleComponent}
      renderLeftComponent={this.renderLeftComponent}
    />);
```

and the headerStyle

```
 headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: colors.appBarBackgroundColor,
    borderBottomWidth: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? StyleSheet.hairlineWidth : 0,
  },
```

Edited: 
Here's the color used in the project

```
errorColor: '#d31100',
primaryColor: '#292929',
secondaryColor: '#929292',
controlColor: '#212121',
secondaryControlColor: '#ffb300',
appBarBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
```

Thanks